# Argument type is not assignable to parameter type

Tags: c#, .net, types

I have such code:

```
List<Pair<string, string>> docs = new List<Pair<string, string>>(); 
iErr = ftpconnect.ListAllDocuments(docs, build.BuildId.ToString());
```

Interface prototype of ListAllDocuments is:

```
Int32 ListAllDocuments(List<Pair<string, string>> DocList, string Path);
```

And I get an error

> Error   21:    The best overloaded method match for 'OperatorPanelWrapper.FtpTransportLibWrapper.ListAllDocuments(System.Collections.Generic.List<OperatorPanel.Pair<string,string>>, string)' has some invalid arguments

Why do I get this error?

Comment: What is your `Pair` class ?

Comment: It's my template class for a usual Pair

Comment: What about other errors? Typically you will get a second error that says what's wrong with the types.

Comment: I see two possibilities: 1) You loaded two versions of a certain assembly, for example by using a strong name in one place, and a normal name in another. 2) `List` or `Pair` is defined in two different assemblies.

Answer (score 3):

In the first code you posted (`new List<Pair<string, string>>()`), try putting your cursor in `Pair` and see where Visual Studio thinks it is defined. It should display `OperatorPanel.Pair<T1, T2>`. If it displays the name of a `Pair` type defined somewhere else (or an error), then your type is wrong.

There are several possibilities:

- You have another `Pair` class defined somewhere (maybe unintentionally) and it is referring to the wrong one.
- You are missing a [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) at the top to specify in which namespace the compiler should look for your `Pair`.
- You have a `using` directive of a different namespace that contains a [`Pair` which is not the one you want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pair.aspx) (e.g. `using System.Web.UI`).
- You are missing a reference to the DLL in which your `Pair` is defined.
- Your `List<T>` reference is somehow wrong (maybe you defined your own?)
- (Unlikely) You have defined your own `ToString` on whatever `BuildId` is, that does not return a `string`.

Basically, check all your types. First in the calling code: does `List` refer to `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, does `Pair` refer to the generic `OperatorPanel.Pair<T1, T2>`...

Comment: Everything is ok with that, it is OperatorPanel.Pair

Comment: @user2071019: Check your other types too.

Comment: @user2071019 - from your comment it sounds like Virtlink's second point about the `using` directive is the solution. You should mark this as your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
List<OperatorPanel.Pair<string, string>> docs = new List<OperatorPanel.Pair<string, string>>();
```

Comment: I did, but there is no necessity to write OperatorPanel.